# Recursive sql query for webpage URL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgresql but if there's a generic sql way even better.

I have a table storing data for webpages, including slug (e.g. in example.com/x/y, x and y are both slugs) and parent_id (x and y each have a record in this table. x's id matches y's parent_id).

If I have the id for y, is there an easy way to find out the full URL (/x/y)? Or at least all the id's (/x_id/y_id)?

I know that I can get this for this particular example like this:

```
select parent_id from pages where slug like 'x';
```

=> 5

And get the slug for that id:

```
select slug from pages where id = (select parent_id
  from pages where slug like 'x');
```

=> y

But what if the URI was more like /a/b/c/d/e/f/g? Is there an easy way to find all of that if all I have is the id for g?

Comment: Search this site for "recursive common table expression". Or check the Postgres manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html (which is ANSI SQL and therefor a "generic SQL way")

Comment: I wonder why someone down voted my question? Feels like a poke in the ribs.

Comment: I guess they're trying to tell me I shouldn't ask questions like this... But WHY?

Comment: I'm just some guy, really stressed out, trying to get a whole ton of stuff done before this ridiculous deadline, but I guess it was really important that I know that my question is invalid.

Comment: @David: Probably for the reason the question is getting closed: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: @Denis thank you for your constructive and instructive feedback. I really value it. Thank you.

Comment: Reasonable reasons to downvote here would include lack of sample data and expected results, no PostgreSQL version, no discussion of anything you already tried/read before posting. That said, random drive-by downvotes are also just a hazard of being here.

Comment: Thank you @CraigRinger. I've definitely lost perspective a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

As @a_hourse-with_no_name said a recursive CTE should take care of you.  This is my favorite link for CTE's: [CTE Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/)

Comment: Note that unlike SQL Server Postgres requires the keyword `RECURSIVE` to make a recursive CTE (this is in compliance with the SQL standard which also makes that keyword mandatory)